# Error while converting DICOM to JPEG

Tags: java, image, jpeg, dicom

i was working on the code to convert a DICOM Iamge (.dcm) to JPEG format - here is the code i used, it is giving me a:
javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi:Provider com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.pcx.PCXImageReaderSpi not found ERROR ...

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.ImageReader;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream;

import org.dcm4che.imageio.plugins.DcmImageReadParam;
import org.dcm4che.util.BufferedOutputStream;
import org.dcm4che2.imageio.plugins.dcm.DicomImageReadParam;
public class DicomToJpeg
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //our DICOM file
        File my`enter code here`DicomFile = new File("IM-0001-0001.dcm");

    //declaring our JPEG image
    BufferedImage myJpegImage = null;

    //iterator containing all registered ImageReades that claim to decome the name format
    Iterator<ImageReader> iter= ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("DICOM");

    //geting our ImageReader object
    ImageReader reader = (ImageReader) iter.next();

    //getting the parameters to read the DICOM image 
    DicomImageReadParam param = (DicomImageReadParam)reader.getDefaultReadParam();

    try
    {
        ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(myDicomFile);
        reader.setInput(iis,false);
        myJpegImage = reader.read(0,param);
        iis.close();

        if(myJpegImage==null)
        {
            System.out.println("\nError: Couldn't read teh dicom image!");
            return;
        }

        File myJpegFile = new File("OutputJpegImage.jpg");
        OutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream( new FileOutputStream(myJpegFile));
        ImageIO.write(myJpegImage, "jpeg", output);
        output.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
           System.out.println("\nError: couldn't read dicom image!"+ e.getMessage());
           return;
    }
}
```

}

This is the error i am receiving ? any idea what am i missing

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi:   Provider com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.pcx.PCXImageReaderSpi not found
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.registerApplicationClasspathSpis(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.getDefaultInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at dcm4chee.DicomToJpeg.main(DicomToJpeg.java:29)
```

Comment: You are missing some code here ;)
read this, please: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Another thing, it's important to tell exactly at wich line the exception (in this case) happens :) Just to make life easier to other to help you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Somewhere* in your classpath, you haven an entry (a file or a resource inside a JAR), named:

```
/META-INF/services/javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi
```

...containing (at least) the line:

```
com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.pcx.PCXImageReaderSpi
```

Whenever `ImageIO` is initialized, or an invocation of `ImageIO.scanForPlugins()` is made, the `IIORegistry/ServiceLoader` will scan the class path for resources matching the name above. For each line in this file/resource, it will try to instantiate the class with the given name (typically a service provider). If the class can't be found, or can't be instantiated (access protection, missing constructor etc.), it will fail with a `ServiceConfigurationError`.

See for example [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/spi/ServiceRegistry.html) for more information.

To fix, you either need to remove the file or the JAR containing the resource (or edit it out of the JAR), or remove the line containing the bad service provider. Alternatively, add the service provider to your class path (I think it's normally in a JAR called `jai_imageio.jar`). But I don't think you'll need PCX (ZSoft Paintbrush format) support to decode DICOM.

Comment: In implementation-dependent configurations where either a non-compilable class file or a missing class might be included in your services file, you can loop through the services using hasNext() and next() enclosing the next() method in a try-catch and catch the ServiceConfigurationError (it is catchable).

Comment: @user579013 The lookup is JRE code, so you can’t really change the behavior in client code. Also, as the services file and implementation class typically go in the same JAR, this is a situation that shouldn’t happen, unless the JAR itself is broken and completely untested.

Comment: Not trying to change the behavior of the JRE code.  Service implementations do not have to reside within the same jar as the ServiceLoader.load code (in fact, usually doesn't) and an example where ServiceConfigurationError will occur is when you have an implementation class that utilizes a package that is not present in the JVM but there might be another implementation class written to not use that package.

Comment: @user579013 1: The service lookup where you suggest to catch the `ServiceConfigurationError` above *is* implemented in JRE code, and must be handled there to keep the registry in a consistent state. 2. I said service implementation and `META-INF/services` entry is in the same JAR. Not what you imply above. 3. The service implementation may gracefully handle this situation itself too. But given 2), just remove the bad JAR from class path and you are good. Simpler logic, more deterministic behaviour. PS: If you believe you have a solution the original question, please post it. Otherwise, stop.

Comment: I will post an answer with sample code.  It does not have to be done within the JRE.

Answer (score -1):

```
static
{
    for (Iterator<urclass> im = ServiceLoader.load(urclass.class).iterator(); im.hasNext();)
        try
        {
            urclass tclass = im.next();
        }
        catch (ServiceConfigurationError e)
        {
        }
}
```

This is a sample where the lookup is not done in the JRE and allows classes that can't be instantiated.